# String match() Method

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `match()` method (For search operation) in my angularjs controller.

Given below is an example :

```
angular.lowercase(value.wor_order_name).match(search)
```

`search` is a variable.

But I face an issue while doing this.If value.wor_order_name is null it returns an error.

Error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null`

Is there any solution?

Comment: See this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183614/cannot-read-property-length-of-null-in-javascript-for-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
angular.lowercase(value.wor_order_name || '').match(search)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is null:

```
if(value.wor_order_name != null){
    angular.lowercase(value.wor_order_name).match(search);
}else{
    //some error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for null

```
    if (value.wor_order_name) {
   angular.lowercase(value.wor_order_name).match(search);
}
```

this will check for the existence of the value in the variable. and then only let you check for the Matching string